# Is there a way to check if a user had an active subscription at a point in the past?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

When I restore the user's purchases in ther iOS device, they can access the content if the subscription is currently active. What I want to do is grant access to the content published in the past if they had an active subscription then.

Example:

Anne purchases a 6 month subscription to a magazine on January 1st. When it ends she doesn't renew it. Then in October she has to format the iPad and reinstall the app. When she wants to download the February issue, is there a way to know that the subscription was active then?

Comment: Are you storing the subscriptions in a database?

Comment: Yes, but I can't find a link between the data I have and the restored transactions, like a user ID or something similar. This is more a problem when the user installs the app in a new device and restores purchases there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check in app receipt, where you can find Subscription original Purchase date and subscription Expiration or Cancellation Date. [Here is documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW6)

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't know how I missed this page in the docs.